# Excel-VBA rename and save to alternate directory without user intervention

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of excel spreadsheets that need to change their filename and save to an alternate path.I have run into a wall trying to attempt this on my own.

---

**The original filename:** *A0001_lp_profile.csv* (the A000# will not always be A0001)

**The new filename:** *A0001.RecentlyOpenedFiles.LNK.xlsx*

The first five characters will not change during the rename.

---

**The original path:** *E:\Backup\VSNMM-01691\Cases\VSNMM-01691.A0001\Exports_fileFolderOpening*

**The new path:** *E:\Backup\VSNMM-01691\Reports*

VSNMM-01691 will not always be in the path and changes quite often to something in a similar format. The "E:\Backup\" will always be the beginning of the path.

Comment: Changing an extension from `.csv` to `.xlsx` is going to cause you (or, at least, future users) problems.  They will see the `.xlsx` extension and think that it is an Excel workbook, when it is actually a text file!  (Unless it is already an Excel workbook, which someone has renamed to be `.csv` in order to confuse **you**.  In that case, renaming it back would be a good idea.)

Comment: P.S.  Just tested and, sure enough, Excel won't open it once the extension is changed to `.xlsx` - it says the file is corrupt (because it thinks it needs to unZIP it, but fails because the first two bytes aren't "PK").

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just make sure that i got your paths and filename patterns right:

```
Dim file As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim originalpath As String, newpath As String

originalpath = "E:\Backup\VSNMM-01691\Cases\VSNMM-01691.A0001\Exports_fileFolderOpening\"
newpath = "E:\Backup\VSNMM-01691\Reports\"

file = Dir(originalpath)

'loop through files in original folder
While (file <> "")

    'match filename with pattern (# means one number, so 4 single numbers) change this if i did it wrong
    If file Like "A####_lp_profile.csv" Then

        'open the csv file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(originalpath & file)

        'save in new path as xlsx (without the Fileformat, the file will be unreadable
        wb.SaveAs newpath & Left(file, 5) & ".RecentlyOpenedFiles.LNK.xlsx", ThisWorkbook.FileFormat

        'close workbook in original path, discard changes
        wb.Close False

        'clear variable
        Set wb = Nothing
    End If

    'next file
    file = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you! This was able to work when I changed the extension from ".xlsx" to ".xls." If the path changes to E:\Backup\ABCDE-01234\Cases\ABCDE-01234.A0002\Exports\_filefolderopening\, would I need to go into the code to change the path every time a change like this is made?

Comment: Right now, yes. But you can change the code to get the path from a cell on the sheet for example: `originalpath = Range("A1").Value`